# Matlab: finding change points in cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

If I have a cell array

```
CELLS = {'AB','AB','AB','BC','BC','CD','CD','CD','DF','FG'}
```

How do I find the indices of the locations at which the elements change?

in this example I'm looking for an output like:

```
CHANGES = 
        4 
        6 
        9
        10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a generic cell array of string call `unique()`, and `find(diff(...))`  the position index:

```
s = {'AB','AB','AB','BC','BC','CD','CD','CD','DF','FG'};
[~,~,p] = unique(s)
find(diff(p)==1)+1
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

`CHANGES = find(diff(cell2mat(CELLS)))+1`

Comment: I accidentally oversimplified my question a bit: what if `CELLS = {'AB','AB','AB','BC','BC','CD','CD','CD','DF','FG'}`?